Minimize pyramid volume
Given a sphere with radius $r$, find the height of a pyramid of minimum volume whose base
is a square and whose base and triangular faces are all tangent to the sphere. This is a problem from Stewart's Calculus. Now the volume of the pyramid is $(1/3)A h$, where $A$ is the area of the base (square) and $h$ is the height. But, how do I relate height to the radius ? . There are three points, top of the pyramid, center of the sphere and the point where sphere is touching the base. Are these three points lie on the same line ?

Maybe try the 2D version first to get a feel for the problem: Enclose a circle in a triangle. Hint: a tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius at the point of tangency.

To address the second question, the alignment condition doesn't seem to be a hypothesis (i.e. the pyramid being right).

Good point, @SassatelliGiulio. We can't assume symmetry, we have to prove it.

So, if I consider the 2D version, then the center of the circle is the point of intersection of three angle bisectors. This is a result from Geometry. But, again, we have 3 points here. Top of circle, center of the circle and the point where the circle touches the base side. How to prove that these are on the same line ? This fact is required for further progress

Here's a ray-trace I did a few years ago of a similar problem, but using a cone instead of a pyramid. https://i.sstatic.net/9QNMj3jK.jpg

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter
